# Get next and previous row based on SQL ordered by two text columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The above is used on the index page.

On the details page, I use

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = :id
```

How can I get the previous and next row based on the current row id?  (the prev and next one ordered by last_name ASC, first_name ASC)

I assume it would be something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM members WHERE last_name >= : last_name AND id != :id ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC
```

But that is not right. I also need to add first_name to the statement somehow, and just doing first_name >= : first_name is not correct.

Comment: so you have an id and you want the prior and the next if the table was ordered by last_name?

Comment: @Hogan - that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` along with `order by` and `limit`.  The following gets the previous name in the first subquery and the next name in the second:

```
(select m.*
 from members m
 where last_name < (select last_name from members where id = :id)
 order by last_name desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select m.*
 from members m
 where last_name > (select last_name from members where id = :id)
 order by last_name asc
 limit 1
);
```

Probably the easiest way to handle first and last names is to concatenate them together:

```
(select m.*
 from members m
 where concat_ws(' ', last_name, first_name) < (select concat_ws(' ', last_name, first_name) from members where id = :id)
 order by last_name asc, first_name desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select m.*
 from members m
 where concat_ws(' ', last_name, first_name) > (select concat_ws(' ', last_name, first_name) from members where id = :id)
 order by last_name asc, first_name
 limit 1
)
```

This could have slightly unexpected results in cases where the first and/or last name have spaces in them.  I'm guessing that does not happen in the data, but other separators could be used in that case.

Comment: I think this works best if there is an index on last_name -- otherwise you probably want to use the technique described by @Quassnoi here http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/  He's using a group by there which isn't needed so it could be simplified.